# ul inside ul on one line with jquery's tag-it plugin

Tags: jquery, css, tag-it

im using [Tag-it](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/) jquery plugin which works on a ul element.

i have a horizontal list (a ul with several li elements) and i want to add to the main horizontal list another li element that will contain the Tag-it ul list.

the problem is that i cannot make the tag-it element be on the same line, even though the elements before it are on the same line.

again - the question is not about making a horizontal list. it is about making a ul inside a ul all on one line.

example:

```
    <ul style="list-style:none; padding-left:0;">
    <li style="display: inline;"> 1 </li>
    <li style="display: inline;"> 2 </li>
    <li style="display: inline;"> 3 </li>
    <li style="display: inline;"> 
        <ul style="list-style:none; padding-left:0;">
            <li style="display: inline;"> a </li>
            <li style="display: inline;"> b </li>
            <li style="display: inline;"> c </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

here is the example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zWvrz/)

thanks allot!

**edit:**

suggested answers although work for the simple example does not work with the tag-it plug in - the one i am concerned in this question. so i edited to title and here are the examples that does not work with current answers
[example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/zWvrz/8/) 
[example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/zWvrz/7/)

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this?

Comment: i edited and added an example

Comment: You mean like this: http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/3fdbdf3a9d818cef95c6e90555852140 ??

Comment: Can you just add a `display: inline` to your nested `ul` element? ([See this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zWvrz/1/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inline everything so you can get it in one line.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 2 </li>
    <li> 3 </li>
    <li> 
        <ul>
            <li> a </li>
            <li> b </li>
            <li> c </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul { border: 1px solid; }
ul li { display: inline; }
ul ul { display: inline-table;   border: 1px solid; }
ul ul li { display: inline; }
```

UPDATE: Change the ul ul to inline-table. I updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zWvrz/9/).

Comment: hi, this does not work correctly with the tag-it plugin. the order is reversed. can you help? http://jsfiddle.net/zWvrz/7/ or this http://jsfiddle.net/zWvrz/8/

Comment: I updated the fiddle and the code. that fixes the order. It's that what you were looking?

Comment: hi, thanks! it seems to work - can you explain why use inline-table ? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unordered lists are `display: block` by default. In order to make them display inline, you simply have to set the `<ul>` to `display: inline` as well.